# Calling Azure function synchronously, without HttpTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to test a Queue-triggered Azure Function over HTTP (integration test).

Is there any general method to call a deployed Azure Function, *synchronously?*

I have successfully called it with the `admin/functions/{function}` endpoint [as shown here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/423#issuecomment-223836297). But I get `202 Accepted` which is no good - My test needs to wait for the function to complete (and fail if the function failed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The Azure Functions host does not support returning the output of a queue trigger to the admin HTTP endpoint. I suggest looking into the suggestion by Johns-305.

Answer (score 3):

That behavior is driven by the Function, not the client.  So if your Function properly closes the http connection, but continues processing, there's nothing the client can do about that.

So, you can either test through the queue, or have a side function with an HTTP Trigger that calls the same processing method(s) that only returns when it's done.

Comment: I'm confused by your first paragraph - There is no http binding within this function. Anyway, sounds like there isn't a way to do what I want, so I will take your suggestion (extra 'side' function with a http trigger). Thanks.

Comment: @Iain You were asking about using an HTTP Trigger so the Answer is based on that, though the queue will behave the same way, meaning you can ack the queue or push a response while the Function continues to process.  Is there any reason why you Accepted the other Answer?

Comment: (Not important really but...) I wasn't asking about HTTP Trigger. I was using the "admin HTTP endpoint" - see Chris's answer. He is on the MSFT Azure team and gave us the inside detail. All three of us agree on the best workaround :) Thanks.

Comment: @Iain Well, he did tell you to do what I suggested.  :)  I can't edit the commend but HTTP Trigger or http endpoint doesn't matter.  The Function is closing the http connection and continuing processing.  There's nothing you can do about that other than what my Answer suggests.

Comment: @Iain I know that, please read my Answer.  And I know how they work. I'm explaining the behavior you're seeing.  If you find a way to do this other than what I suggest, please come back and let us know.